# How to fix 'failed to register layer: error creating overlay mount' when running docker-compose up?

Tags: docker-compose

I execute docker-compose build with success. The problem is when I execute docker-compose up and the result is the next one: failed to register layer: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/69d1349c3a7901bba59c549416eaec4574d811c9c690904c60bce6c2d72f80de/merged: too many levels of symbolic links
How can I resolve it?

I tried the next comands:

- sudo systemctl restart docker
- docker system prune -af --volumes
- sudo service docker restart

And I look for the solution in multiples blogs